# How to get the Real time when TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK is the state from onCallStateChanged method of PhoneStateListener

Tags: java, android, telephonymanager

I am making a code for making phone calls. Everything successful except that I am unable to get the system time when `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK` state from the `onCallStateChanged(int state,  String incomingNumber)`.

Similarly, I want to get the system time when `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` state is arrived. Once I get both the values in the Mainactivity I can get the difference and based its value I can start some other activity.

For example, if the time difference between `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` state and `TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE` state is less than 30 second, then I can assume that the call is not attended and I can start another call(or to another number). I am able to do all these inside the `onCallStateChanged` Method of `PhoneStateListener` class. But unable to pass this values to Mainactivity either by variables or Methods etc. This is the code for invoking call and it is working fine

```
Intent myIntentCall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:0123456789"));
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                    != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    requestPermissions();
}
else
{
    startActivity(myIntentCall);            

}

private void requestPermissions () {
    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
}
```

From the below piece of code, I expect the updated value of  `_seconds` to the Mainactivity class by accessing `PhoneReceiver._seconds` statement. But always it remain `0`. But I get the correct value for `_seconds` in the `PhoneReceiver` class. The code is given below

```
public class PhoneReceiver extends PhoneStateListener {
    Context context;
    static boolean _callStarted = false;
    long _callStartTime;
    long _callEndTime;
    long _callDuration;
    long _minutes;
    static long _seconds;

    public PhoneReceiver(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

   @Override
   public void onCallStateChanged(int state,  String incomingNumber) {
       if ((state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) && !_callStarted) {
           _callStarted = !_callStarted;
           _callStartTime = new Date().getTime();
           Toast.makeText(context, "Stage 1: " + "Off Hook -> Boolean: "+_callStarted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
       if ((state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) && _callStarted)
       {
            _callEndTime = new Date().getTime();
            _callDuration = _callEndTime - _callStartTime;
            _minutes = (_callDuration / 1000) / 60;
            _seconds = (_callDuration / 1000) % 60;
            Toast.makeText(context, "Stage 2: " + "IDLE State->Boolean: "+_callStarted, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
```

}

Android Manifest.xml is given below

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.callerApppackage.callerapp">

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

    <!-- put this here so that even if the app is not running,
    your app can be woken up if there is a change in phone
    state -->
    <receiver android:name=".PhoneStateReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action
                android:name=
                    "android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


</application>
```

PhonestateReciver Class is given below

```
public class PhoneStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    TelephonyManager manager;
    PhoneReceiver myPhoneStateListener;
    static boolean alreadyListening = false;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        myPhoneStateListener = new PhoneReceiver(context);
        manager = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

        //---do not add the listener more than once---
        if (!alreadyListening) {
            manager.listen(myPhoneStateListener,
                PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
            alreadyListening = true;
        }
    }
}
```

I hope I made it clear Thanking you all in advance for earlier reply.